# Should I serialize an assoc array or dynamically generate tables to story this data?

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I've created a php script to parse my payslip PDFs automatically and want to store them in a database for ease of reference (preferably MySQL for familiarity).

The data I've ended up with (per payslip) is (for example):
(plus around 40 other cols most of which don't change regularly).

```
Array
(
    [assignment] => 123456
    [name] => JOE BLOGS
    [location] => 42 WEST STREET
    [department] => Lancashire
    [job_title] => Imaginary
    [payscale_description] => Generic desciprtion
    [salary] => 12345.00
    [hours] => 40
    [pt_salary] => 12345.00
    [pay] => Array
        (
            [Basic Pay] => 1234.00
            [Additional Hours (OOH)] => 567.00
            [Night Allowance] => 891.10
            [Weekend Allowance] => 112.13
        )

    [deductions] => Array
        (
            [PAYE] => 123.00
            [National Insurance] => 456.00
            [Pension] => 789.00
            [Student Loan] => 101.12
        )

)
```

Now the [Pay] and [Deductions] might change per month (e.g. sometimes there may be expenses / subsistence / car parking etc). The script just creates the assoc arrays but there are approx 20 variable additions / deductions on top of these common ones. Without creating another 20 cols in the MySQL table, so far I've resorted to serialising these two fields with JSON and storing them like that, but then it's difficult to search them / dynamically modify etc.

I'm just wondering if there's an obvious solution that I've missed for dynamic columns (some of which I might not have predicted yet).
I wondered further about dynamically creating a table for each pay / deduction per month and then doing a JOIN when searching but this seemed excessive.

Any help gratefully appreciated!.

Comment: I would recommend that you read up on [database normalization](http://download.nust.na/pub6/mysql/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html) to get an idea how to properly structure a relational database instead of storing serialized data.

Comment: There are extensions for mysql which allow for indexing structured data inside a cell, but that approach is inefficient. If you have dynamically structured data you need to turn away from a strictly structured database. Take a look at nosql databases instead. That is what they are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, beside the `payslip` database table, create a second table called `specification`, or something to that effect. The columns in that table would be `id`, `payslipId`, `title`, and `amount`. Your [pay] and [deductions] would fit into that like so:

```
id  payslipId  title                     amount
1      1     Basic Pay                   1234.00
2      1     Additional Hours (OOH)       567.00
3      1     Night Allowance              891.10
4      1     Weekend Allowance            112.13
5      1     PAYE                        -123.00
6      1     National Insurance          -456.00
7      1     Pension                     -789.00
8      1     Student Loan                -101.12
```

You can add as many [pay] and [deductions] rows as you need.

Note that the `payslipId` column is linking each specification to the correct payslip.

As Magnus Eriksson mentioned in his comment, this is part of "database normalization".

Comment: Thanks so much, that's definitely better than what I'm doing!

Comment: @TomLudlow Yes, it is.  Now when you want to perform a query, which includes the specifications, you do a `JOIN` query. See: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/